# Rails 3: How To Return A JSON Document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm in the process of creating a simple API for my application. I have create the controllers and did all the processing. However, the view is being returned.

How can I return a JSON document to the user instead of the view?

Also, if there's an error, should I also return a JSON document or... ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your controller

```
   respond_to :html, :json
```

(remove html if you only want json-api).

In your actions you can then simply use a respond_with call, like:

```
   respond_with(@posts = Post.all)
```

It will render JSON-object if format is JSON, and it will render your html-view if html is requested. If your routes are created as standard resources, simply adding .json suffix to the url will give you the JSON-result, ie. if the route is specified as:

```
   resources :posts
```

Comment: I've done that but when I do "curl ..." I have no response. How do I get the JSON?

Comment: iceydee's answer should work - I am doing this many times in my own applications.  A few items you might want to check: make sure your html view returns records and verify that you are referencing the correct url/route (including the .json extension)

Comment: Try it in the web-browser, add .json at the end and you should be presented with JSON.